# Singular or plural verb in subordinate clause?

Tags: verbs, plural-forms, subordinate-clauses

In  a book that I am reading (The Great Conversation) I found the following sentence:

> What is just in this social world is that each person **receive** the
>   honor that is due, given that person's status and position.

Is **receive** correct?
Should not it be receive**s**?

Answer (score 4):

It's because this sentence is written in the subjunctive form. It's a very formal way of speaking; and is used for talking about opinions, ideas, and possibilities instead of just facts. If this world *were* just, he would say "everyone receives the honor that is due." But the world is not just, so he's using the subjunctive clause to talk about the ideal situation.

You don't *have* to use the subjunctive clause in this sentence, it would be equally correct to say

> What is just in this social world is that each person receive**s** the honor that is due, given that person's status and position.

The meaning's the same, but because it's not in the subjunctive mood it sounds maybe a little too authoritative. As if he's saying "and that's a fact that everyone agrees with."